# is there an API to work with dual SIM Android phones?

Tags: android, api, sim-card

Is there APIs to work with dual SIM Android phones?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is one in the standard sdk.
You might want to look at android.internal.telephony package

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/